# Can I create a custom PowerShell object with an array property?

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, hashtable, powershell-2.0

Warning:  I am looking to do this in PowerShell v2 (sorry!).

I would like to have a custom object (possibly created as a custom type) that has an array property.  I know how to make a custom object with "noteproperty" properties:

```
$person = new-object PSObject
$person | add-member -type NoteProperty -Name First -Value "Joe"
$person | add-member -type NoteProperty -Name Last -Value "Schmoe"
$person | add-member -type NoteProperty -Name Phone -Value "555-5555"
```

and I know how to make a custom object from a custom type:

```
Add-Type @"
  public struct PersonType {
    public string First;
    public string Last;
    public string Phone;
  }
"@

$person += New-Object PersonType -Property @{
      First = "Joe";
      Last = "Schmoe";
      Phone = "555-5555";
    }
```

How can I create a custom object with a type that includes an array property?  Something like this hash table, but as an object:

```
$hash = @{
    First = "Joe"
    Last  = "Schmoe"
    Pets  = @("Fluffy","Spot","Stinky")
}
```

I'm pretty sure I can do this using `[PSCustomObject]$hash` in PowerShell v3, but I have a need to include v2.

Thanks.

Comment: `New-Object PSObject -Property $hash`

Comment: Any reason for limiting yourself to v2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `Add-Member` to add your note properties, the `-Value` can be an array.

```
$person | add-member -type NoteProperty -Name Pets -Value @("Fluffy","Spot","Stinky")
```

If you want to create the properties as a hashtable first, like your example, you can pass that right into `New-Object` as well:

```
$hash = @{
    First = "Joe"
    Last  = "Schmoe"
    Pets  = @("Fluffy","Spot","Stinky")
}

New-Object PSObject -Property $hash
```

Your `PersonType` example is really written in C#, as a string, which gets compiled on the fly, so the syntax will be the C# syntax for an array property:

```
Add-Type @"
  public struct PersonType {
    public string First;
    public string Last;
    public string Phone;
    public string[] Pets;
  }
"@
```

Comment: Super!  Thanks!  (I swear I had tried the hash table option and got an error, but it's working now!)